# In python, with pandas, change several columns at once and modify some values (of these columns) to fit a predefined range

Tags: python, pandas

After looking at SO, I (think I) could force some columns to become numeric and transform to missing values outside a predefined range. (I think the code is ok).

[image: change values]

However, when I try the same with the real data, I'm receiving the following error
`typeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int`

[image: error]

The simulated data and code: (working)

```
#dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"var_1": [2,"a"], "var_2": [5,7], "var_3": [1,np.NaN], "other_1": [1,9]})
df2
#modify any variable with "var" 
df2.loc[:,df2.columns.str.contains("var")] = df2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') 
df2.loc[:,df2.columns.str.contains("var")] = df2.mask((df2 < 1) | (df2 > 5))
df2
```

The quasi-real dataset and the code (not working):

```
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'aut_a_p1_r1': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p1_r2': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 4.0}, 'aut_a_p1_r3': {105: 5.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 5.0}, 'aut_a_p1_r4': {105: 2, 194: 1, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 3}, 'aut_a_p1_r5': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 1, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p1_r6': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'aut_a_p1_r7': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'aut_a_p1_r8': {105: 3, 194: 2, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 2}, 'aut_a_p1_r9': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: -1.5, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'aut_a_p1_r10': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: -1.4, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p1_r11': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p1_r12': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'aut_a_p1_r13': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'aut_a_p1_r14': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p1_r15': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 5.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 5.0}, 'aut_a_p2_r1': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'aut_a_p2_r2': {105: 4, 194: 3, 93: 2, 297: 1, 131: 1}, 'aut_a_p2_r3': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p2_r4': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'aut_a_p2_r5': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p2_r6': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 2, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'aut_a_p2_r7': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'aut_a_p2_r8': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 2}, 'aut_a_p2_r9': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'aut_a_p2_r10': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'aut_a_p2_r11': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 2}, 'aut_a_p2_r12': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 2}, 'aut_a_p2_r13': {105: 4, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p2_r14': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'aut_a_p2_r15': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 5, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'gpe_a_p1_r1': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'gpe_a_p1_r2': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'gpe_a_p1_r3': {105: 2, 194: 1, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 1}, 'gpe_a_p1_r4': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'gpe_a_p1_r5': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'gpe_a_p1_r6': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'gpe_a_p1_r7': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 2}, 'gpe_a_p1_r8': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'gpe_a_p1_r9': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'gpe_a_p1_r10': {105: 3, 194: 3, 93: 4, 297: 1, 131: 1}, 'gpe_a_p1_r11': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 2}, 'gpe_a_p1_r12': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'gpe_a_p1_r13': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'gpe_a_p1_r14': {105: 3, 194: 2, 93: 2, 297: 5, 131: 1}, 'gpe_a_p1_r15': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 1, 131: 3}, 'gpe_a_p2_r1': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r2': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 1.0, 131: 4.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r3': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 2, 297: 1, 131: 'BLANK'}, 'gpe_a_p2_r4': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 4.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r5': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 5.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 5.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r6': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 1.0, 131: 3.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r7': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r8': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 4.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r9': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 1.0, 131: 3.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r10': {105: 4.0, 194: 3.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r11': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 1.0, 131: 2.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r12': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 2}, 'gpe_a_p2_r13': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 5.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r14': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'gpe_a_p2_r15': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'tdr_a_p1_r1': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 1}, 'tdr_a_p1_r2': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p1_r3': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 3}, 'tdr_a_p1_r4': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p1_r5': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 3}, 'tdr_a_p1_r6': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p1_r7': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 3}, 'tdr_a_p1_r8': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p1_r9': {105: 2, 194: 3, 93: 2, 297: 4, 131: 1}, 'tdr_a_p1_r10': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'tdr_a_p1_r11': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 3}, 'tdr_a_p1_r12': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p1_r13': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p1_r14': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p1_r15': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p2_r1': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p2_r2': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 5, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r3': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 3}, 'tdr_a_p2_r4': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r5': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p2_r6': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r7': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r8': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: -2.4, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p2_r9': {105: 4, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r10': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p2_r11': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r12': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r13': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'tdr_a_p2_r14': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'tdr_a_p2_r15': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'cso_a_p1_r1': {105: 3.0, 194: 1.0, 93: 2.0, 297: nan, 131: 3.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r2': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 2}, 'cso_a_p1_r3': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 5.0, 297: nan, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r4': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 2, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'cso_a_p1_r5': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 3.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r6': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'cso_a_p1_r7': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'cso_a_p1_r8': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'cso_a_p1_r9': {105: 4.0, 194: 3.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r10': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 5.0, 297: nan, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r11': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r12': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 5.0, 297: nan, 131: 4.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r13': {105: 4.0, 194: 2.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 4.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r14': {105: -3.4, 194: 3.0, 93: 2.0, 297: nan, 131: 3.0}, 'cso_a_p1_r15': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r1': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 5, 131: 5}, 'cso_a_p2_r2': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 4.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r3': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r4': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'cso_a_p2_r5': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r6': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r7': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 5, 131: 5}, 'cso_a_p2_r8': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'cso_a_p2_r9': {105: 4.0, 194: 3.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r10': {105: 4, 194: 2, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'cso_a_p2_r11': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r12': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 5.0}, 'cso_a_p2_r13': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 5, 131: 5}, 'cso_a_p2_r14': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: -3.4, 297: 5, 131: 4}, 'cso_a_p2_r15': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 4.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r1': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r2': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 2.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r3': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 5.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r4': {105: 2, 194: 4, 93: 1, 297: 4, 131: 2}, 'rin_a_p1_r5': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 2.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r6': {105: 3, 194: 3, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p1_r7': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r8': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r9': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 2.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r10': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p1_r11': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'rin_a_p1_r12': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 2, 297: 1, 131: 3}, 'rin_a_p1_r13': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 3.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r14': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'rin_a_p1_r15': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 1.0}, 'rin_a_p2_r1': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p2_r2': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p2_r3': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p2_r4': {105: 4, 194: 2, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'rin_a_p2_r5': {105: 4, 194: 3, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'rin_a_p2_r6': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 3}, 'rin_a_p2_r7': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p2_r8': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'rin_a_p2_r9': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'rin_a_p2_r10': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 3}, 'rin_a_p2_r11': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p2_r12': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 3}, 'rin_a_p2_r13': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p2_r14': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'rin_a_p2_r15': {105: 4, 194: 1, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'pcr_a_p1_r1': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 3.0}, 'pcr_a_p1_r2': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 3.0}, 'pcr_a_p1_r3': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 3.0}, 'pcr_a_p1_r4': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'pcr_a_p1_r5': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'pcr_a_p1_r6': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 2, 297: 2, 131: 2}, 'pcr_a_p1_r7': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'pcr_a_p1_r8': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'pcr_a_p1_r9': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'pcr_a_p1_r10': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'pcr_a_p1_r11': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'pcr_a_p1_r12': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'pcr_a_p1_r13': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 2, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'pcr_a_p1_r14': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 3.0}, 'pcr_a_p1_r15': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 5.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r1': {105: 5.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 5.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r2': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 5.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r3': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 4.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r4': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 2, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'pcr_a_p2_r5': {105: 5.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 5.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 4.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r6': {105: 3.0, 194: 1.0, 93: 1.0, 297: 1.0, 131: 2.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r7': {105: 5, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'pcr_a_p2_r8': {105: 5, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'pcr_a_p2_r9': {105: 5, 194: 2, 93: 2, 297: 4, 131: 3}, 'pcr_a_p2_r10': {105: 3, 194: 2, 93: 1, 297: 2, 131: 2}, 'pcr_a_p2_r11': {105: 4, 194: 3, 93: 2, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'pcr_a_p2_r12': {105: 5.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 5.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r13': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 1, 297: 1, 131: 5}, 'pcr_a_p2_r14': {105: 5.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'pcr_a_p2_r15': {105: 2.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 5.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 2.0}, 'det_a_p1_r1': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'det_a_p1_r2': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 4.0}, 'det_a_p1_r3': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 5.0}, 'det_a_p1_r4': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'det_a_p1_r5': {105: 3.0, 194: 1.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 1.0}, 'det_a_p1_r6': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p1_r7': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 5.0}, 'det_a_p1_r8': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p1_r9': {105: 3, 194: 1, 93: 2, 297: 3, 131: 1}, 'det_a_p1_r10': {105: 4.0, 194: 1.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 1.0}, 'det_a_p1_r11': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p1_r12': {105: 2, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p1_r13': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'det_a_p1_r14': {105: 2, 194: 1, 93: 2, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p1_r15': {105: 1.0, 194: 2.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 5.0, 131: 1.0}, 'det_a_p2_r1': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 3.0}, 'det_a_p2_r2': {105: 2.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'det_a_p2_r3': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}, 'det_a_p2_r4': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'det_a_p2_r5': {105: 5, 194: 3, 93: 5, 297: 4, 131: 2}, 'det_a_p2_r6': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'det_a_p2_r7': {105: 3.0, 194: 2.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 1.0}, 'det_a_p2_r8': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p2_r9': {105: 3, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p2_r10': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p2_r11': {105: 3, 194: 2, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p2_r12': {105: 2, 194: 4, 93: 2, 297: 3, 131: 5}, 'det_a_p2_r13': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'det_a_p2_r14': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'det_a_p2_r15': {105: 4, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'lid_a_p1_r1': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 4.0}, 'lid_a_p1_r2': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 3.0, 297: nan, 131: 3.0}, 'lid_a_p1_r3': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 3}, 'lid_a_p1_r4': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 4}, 'lid_a_p1_r5': {105: 4.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 2.0, 297: nan, 131: 4.0}, 'lid_a_p1_r6': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 4.0}, 'lid_a_p1_r7': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 4.0}, 'lid_a_p1_r8': {105: 1.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 5.0, 297: nan, 131: 5.0}, 'lid_a_p1_r9': {105: -1.5, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: nan, 131: 3}, 'lid_a_p1_r10': {105: 1, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'lid_a_p1_r11': {105: 2, 194: 2, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 2}, 'lid_a_p1_r12': {105: 1, 194: 1, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 1}, 'lid_a_p1_r13': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 4, 297: nan, 131: 5}, 'lid_a_p1_r14': {105: 3.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 4.0, 297: nan, 131: 3.0}, 'lid_a_p1_r15': {105: 3, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: nan, 131: 3}, 'lid_a_p2_r1': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 5}, 'lid_a_p2_r2': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 4}, 'lid_a_p2_r3': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 4, 297: 3, 131: 3}, 'lid_a_p2_r4': {105: 3, 194: 5, 93: 2, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'lid_a_p2_r5': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 3}, 'lid_a_p2_r6': {105: 4, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'lid_a_p2_r7': {105: 5, 194: 5, 93: 5, 297: 4, 131: 4}, 'lid_a_p2_r8': {105: 2, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 5}, 'lid_a_p2_r9': {105: 3, 194: 4, 93: 3, 297: 2, 131: 4}, 'lid_a_p2_r10': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 4.0, 131: 5.0}, 'lid_a_p2_r11': {105: 3, 194: 3, 93: 3, 297: 3, 131: 3}, 'lid_a_p2_r12': {105: 2.0, 194: 4.0, 93: 2.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 5.0}, 'lid_a_p2_r13': {105: 5.0, 194: 3.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 3.0, 131: 4.0}, 'lid_a_p2_r14': {105: 3.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 4.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 3.0}, 'lid_a_p2_r15': {105: 4.0, 194: 5.0, 93: 3.0, 297: 2.0, 131: 4.0}}
)

df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("_a_")] = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') 
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("_a_")] = df.mask((df < 1) | (df > 5))
df
```

Comment: With the data you shared, I don't get any errors. Do you? From the error, it seems you have some datetime type column(s). Use `df.info()` to get the types of your Dataframe. 
You can find which column(s) is a datetime type with `df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64'])`
 However, there is one column (gpe_a_p2_r3) that is of type object because it has a value  `BLANK`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this issue. with the real dataframe, I'm receiving this warning `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int` when I use the `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("_a_")] = df.mask((df < 1) | (df > 5))` argument.

Comment: As I was saying, you have at least one column that is casted as a datetime instead of a numerical. Can you please give the result of `df.info()` and `df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64'])` so we can identify which column is the issue then you can either remove it or identify the row that is the issue.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. You`re right. After `df.info`, `dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(492), int64(2), object(230)` retruned. And after `datetime`, the variable `datanasc` returned. I (wrongly) thought that using  `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("_a_")] = df.mask((df < 1) | (df > 5))` the function will just use these variables with "_a_" and skip the `datanasc` variable. What can I can from now? Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you `df.loc` works as you expect it to work but you apply the `mask` on the full `df`. I would do this instead:

```py
df_a_columns = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("_a_")] 
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("_a_")] = df_a_columns.mask((df_a_columns < 1) | (df_a_columns > 5))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Is there any possibility to optimize the code to not use the same variables on both sides of the equation all the time? 
See that `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("_a_")]` is placed at the right and the left ?
(I ask that because I tend to use R as well and the `pipe` operator provides this function). Thank you again!!